# YouTube limitations of get_video_info

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

There are some restriction with limitations of using `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=[ID]`?

Returned data are better for me, more then Google Youtube Data API and does not require OAuth or API key.

Comment: so, whats your question?

Comment: I can't find information about limitations of using `/get_video_info`, something like connection per hour or day...

Answer (score 2):

get_video_info  is part of YouTube not part of the YouTube API its an end point used by the YouTube website.   Thats why you dont need an api key to access it.

One could argue that by hacking the Youtube website in this manner you are going against the [Youtube terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service)

It would be best to go though the YouTube API thats what its there for.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this file is public and I can check if video is live streaming

Comment: The file may be public use the API endpoints Google supplies not the endpoints ment for their use

Comment: it seems this endpoint may finally have been shut down https://stackoverflow.com/q/67615278/1841839