# get_video_info API stopped working, App failed to play video using this API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using URL getting from Below api for playing youtube video in App
https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=KVh4KtUSW3A&html5=1

But Now This Api also stopped working
Anyone know allternative API for playing youtube video in app

Comment: Do you have any error details? - if you click that link, you will get the response. It's not clear about what is your problem with this response... read [ask] and [edit] your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_video\_info YouTube endpoint suddenly returning 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615278/get-video-info-youtube-endpoint-suddenly-returning-404-not-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like:

`https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={video_id}&html5=1&c=TVHTML5&cver=6.20180913`.

Comment: @saurabhgoyal795 it stopped working a few days ago, damn it, YouTube/Google - they removed it, it seems...any alternatives?

Comment: there is one alternative but it's working only for public videos. please check this https://reqbin.com/9d2xjrp2

Comment: yes i have got a alternative and i have modified extractor file too