# How to identify the YouTube videos that can't embed on file

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-data-api

I have a mobile application that embeds some youtube videos in a webview.

The problem is that, using YouTube Data API v3 I get a list of "*Embeddable*" items to show. But some of them say that "Video unavailable". When I paste the same code on on jsfiddle or a domain or some sort of **webserver**, it **does work** but when reading from **File** or navigating to html string via **webview**, it **doesn't work**.

My question is that how can I understand if the video that I'm trying to **embed** is actually *embeddable* from **file** or not?

I have checked youtube data API v3 outputs for each video and I couldn't find any meaningful information.

Is there some other sort of web API or HTTP endpoint that I can check to see if the video is right?

If not, how can I get data from youtube player programatically to see whether it successfully embedded it or not?

The sample list of the youtube videos that can't be embedded in file are following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjI3bzvbCU4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWveXdj6oZU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEEnap_h8cs
```

[image]

Note: My problem is to **identify** the *unimbeddable* items, because I want to load them from *file* (in a mobile app). Therefore trying to **loading** it from a **webserver isn't** an option for me.

Note 2: These blocks aren't regional, they are domain based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube Data API v3 [provides](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=player&id=TjI3bzvbCU4&key=API_KEY) [a not working embed page](https://www.youtube.com/embed/TjI3bzvbCU4) [while it says that it is](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=TjI3bzvbCU4&key=API_KEY).

While for other videos like this one (`ZqYezph-hgg`) [it works](https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZqYezph-hgg).

So my idea is just to retrieve https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID and see if the video is unplayable like this for instance:

`curl -s https://www.youtube.com/embed/TjI3bzvbCU4 | grep "UNPLAYABLE" | wc -l`

Returns `1`, so this video is unplayable.

`curl -s https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZqYezph-hgg | grep "UNPLAYABLE" | wc -l`

Returns `0`, so this video is playable.

Also note that my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/c8e59bfd5ec4f7aae67e0069f565585f794287ee/videos.php#L100) [YouTube operational API](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) implements more properly this feature, as https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=status&id=TjI3bzvbCU4 returns:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "TjI3bzvbCU4",
            "status": {
                "embeddable": true,
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=status&id=ZqYezph-hgg returns:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "ZqYezph-hgg",
            "status": {
                "embeddable": true,
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Basically this method sends a request to the embedding endoint and checks for the word "UNPLAYABLE" in it's content. It can be easily implemented in any programming language

Comment: Also I added a "Accept-Language=en" header to make sure I always get the results in English

Comment: The `Accept-Language=en` isn't required because `UNPLAYABLE` is written in YouTube JSON answer as a value for `status` so not shown to the end-user so not translated.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [entry on Google Support](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/20562339?hl=en&msgid=32097030) that *might* explain why a video is not available.

Quote:

> Actually found the issue here. **The videos that were displaying this on
> embed had "Copyrighted" music playing in the background. YouTube
> apparently does not play videos like this while embedded.** We had our
> user remove the audio and re-uploaded the video and everything is
> working fine now.
>
> Hope this helps somebody.

Probably, YouTube Data API is not updated to match the value set by the uploader/owner of the video AND YouTube guidelines to allow embed the videos.

For this case, I suggest you to post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).

If you enter to the source code of the video - like: `view-source:https://www.youtube.com/embed/TjI3bzvbCU4`, you can find there a property called **`previewPlayabilityStatus`** as follows:

```json
"previewPlayabilityStatus": {
    "status": "UNPLAYABLE",
    "reason": "Video no disponible",
    "errorScreen": {
        "playerErrorMessageRenderer": {
            "reason": {
                "runs": [{
                    "text": "Video no disponible"
                }]
            },
            "proceedButton": {
                "buttonRenderer": {
                    "style": "STYLE_DEFAULT",
                    "size": "SIZE_DEFAULT",
                    "isDisabled": false,
                    "text": {
                        "simpleText": "Mirar en YouTube"
                    },
                    "navigationEndpoint": {
                        "clickTrackingParams": "CAEQ8FsiEwiT6sGfg6j3AhVG25QJHY96Amgu003d"
```

This info was available throught this endpoint: **`https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=TjI3bzvbCU4`**, but, now, an *`HTTP ERROR 410`* is returned.

Unfortunately, this info does not provide any useful data about the reason(s) why the video is not available - despite the fact the [response of the YouTube Data API says is is embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22TjI3bzvbCU4%22%5D%7D):

```json
"status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true,
    "madeForKids": false
  },
```

You can also use [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541599) for embed a YouTube video - I share it here because I find it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your referer and referer-policy set in the header all requests.