# Embeddable Youtube video is not embedabble

Tags: youtube

For this Youtube video the share option is available -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZkrVyILOYA

But when I embed this video on my website I get the message 'Not available'. Also when linked to directly I get this message -> https://www.youtube.com/embed/CZkrVyILOYA

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71970621/7123660).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an iframe
this works fine for me

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CZkrVyILOYA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

My website didn't send a referrer in the request. Now it does and all youtube video's can be embedded.