# How do I know If a Video Becomes Unavailable in YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: youtube

When I request a snippet, statistics, status, on video Id: darZbXulSDI
I am receiving that its status is public.

```json
  "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true,
    "madeForKids": false
  },
  "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "4",
    "likeCount": "1538",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "0"
  }
```

but on YouTube page, It shows unavailable.
I also can't explain how the likes count exceeds the view count :)

What is the best way to check if a video becomes unavailable?
And did the creator unlist this video, made it private, or deleted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how creators, if they are able to, make their videos unavailable.

Note that [Subscribe to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) sends a notification when a video of the tracked channel becomes private or unlisted or is deleted, for each of this case you will receive for instance:

```xml
<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>
<feed xmlns:at="http://purl.org/atompub/tombstones/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><at:deleted-entry ref="yt:video:1RHxvM8mQS4" when="2022-10-24T13:39:07.99031+00:00">
  <link href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RHxvM8mQS4"/>
  <at:by>
   <name>Test</name>
   <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ</uri>
  </at:by>
 </at:deleted-entry></feed>
```

For an unlisted video (such as [`8c-AHRlzyJs`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8c-AHRlzyJs)) you can retrieve this information from [`status/privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=snippet`.

Graphically you would get:

[image: private video UI rendering]

For such a private video, `Videos: list` won't return you any item for the given YouTube video `id` (if you aren't using OAuth 2 by being logged as the creator of the given video).

For a deleted video you would graphically get:

[image: deleted video UI rendering]

For [the video `darZbXulSDI`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=darZbXulSDI) you sent, graphically you get:

[image: provided video UI rendering]

To distinguish both of them as [they are both unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71975098), you can use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/899316c549c4255f3b13f1884b11b459d8b2e2de) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=status&id=VIDEO_ID, you would get whether or not the video was deleted by his uploader by reading `item["status"]["removedByTheUploader"]`.

Note that as *we don't know* how the video went unavailable and as people are able to like the video without watching it, this may explains how the likes count exceeds the view count.

Comment: Hello, I tried your library: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/videos?part=snippet,status&id=darZbXulSDI and I got the exact same reply as V3 API, public status, and publicStatsViewable = true, does your API pull data directly from youtube.com?

Comment: @bobmason Indeed https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/YOUR_REQUEST retrieves YouTube Data API v3 content in a quota-free manner as explained on https://yt.lemnoslife.com However I haven't mentioned my YouTube no-key service in my answer. You are looking for my YouTube operational API and more precisely https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=status&id=darZbXulSDI Note that YouTube operational API retrieves its content from [YouTube UI](https://www.youtube.com) endpoints.

Comment: I got it! was a little confused, but great job, I already joined your discord...