# PlaylistItems doesn't showing all VideoNames

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use youtube reporting API to get VideoIDs and some metrics. Then I also use Youtube Data API to get list of ALL VideoNames. But when I combine these two groups (to get names to these IDs), I found out that a lot of names are missing.

HTTP request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems

What is the best HTTP request to get ALL existing VideoNames historically?
Why playlistItems doesn't work properly and not showing all VideoNames?
Thank you

```
def get_videos():
  for f in glob.glob(f'YoutubeAnalytics/videos/*.json'):
    os.unlink(f)  
  for ch_name, token_file, ch_id in channels:
    print(ch_name)
    print(ch_id, 'UU' + ch_id[2:])
    jsn = json.load(open(TOKEN_PATH + token_file))
    svc = get_youtube_data(jsn)
    name = token_file.replace('.json', '')
    rsp = svc.playlistItems().list(part='snippet', playlistId= 'UU' + ch_id[2:], maxResults=50).execute()
    # rsp = svc.channels().list(part='id,snippet', mine=True).execute()
    i = 0
    while 1:
        # tak se to stahne to originalniho folderu Python
      with open(f'YoutubeAnalytics/videos/{name}_{i:04d}.json', 'w') as w:
        json.dump(rsp, w)
      if 'nextPageToken' in rsp:
        i += 1
        if i % 10 == 0: 
          print(i)
        rsp = svc.playlistItems().list(part='snippet', playlistId= 'UU' + ch_id[2:], maxResults=50, pageToken=rsp['nextPageToken']).execute()
      else:
        break


def make_videos_csv():
  htag = re.compile(r"\s#\S+")
  with open(f'YoutubeAnalytics/videos/videos.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvf:
      wrt = csv.writer(csvf)
      for f in glob.glob(f'YoutubeAnalytics/videos/*.json'):
          jsn = json.load(open(f))
          for i in jsn['items']:
              snip = i['snippet']
              descr = snip['description']
              tags = ','.join([ t[1:] for t in htag.findall(descr) ])
              wrt.writerow((snip['resourceId']['videoId'], i['id'], i['etag'], snip['channelId'], snip['publishedAt'][:-1], snip['title'], snip['description'], tags))
```

Comment: Can you share us your algorithms/the requests you do?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, piece of my code attached. Function get_videos() - downloading files

Comment: Can you also provide a video id that is missing by using your provided algorithm?

Comment: @Luciebix please [edit] and post the code here - is not easy to debug code in an image. Also, add some video_ids that you got without name.

Comment: For example these Video_IDs I got using Reporting API but did not get the names using Data API, 
zzr8YwY0y2U,
zypHHsc3Q_Y,
zyXCdTAdL2s,
zvgtoZvL-Gs

Comment: Hi, do you have any answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that some videos *may be marked as private*, then, **if you're not the owner of the video(s), you wont be able to get the details of such video(s)**.

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75254226/playlistitems-doesnt-showing-all-videonames#comment132813380_75254226), you added these video_ids examples:

```
zzr8YwY0y2U, zypHHsc3Q_Y, zyXCdTAdL2s, zvgtoZvL-Gs
```

Here are the results of each one:

- `zzr8YwY0y2U` = Catch the Crooks - LEGO City - mini movie: Ep. 13
- `zypHHsc3Q_Y` = LEGO Marvel: Spider-Man 'Vexed By Venom' Episode 4: Paging Ghost-Spider
- `zyXCdTAdL2s` = **PUBLIC INFO NOT AVAILABLE** - this video is *private*.
- `zvgtoZvL-Gs` = ～どんなどうぶつが暮らすサファリをつくる？篇～「みやぞんとあらぽんがつくる！つながる、ひろがる、 レゴ シティ！」

See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71970621/12511801) and modify your code in order to handle such *unavailable* video(s) you might get with your current code - or just accept that you cannot get data **if those video(s) are not publicly available**.