# How do i use Youtube Api Embed Filter Research on normal YT?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, embed, youtube-data-api, embeddable

im looking for a way to filter videos that are embeddable only to put in my application and since there isn't such filter on YT,

I found the Youtube Api and started experimenting with it, i found the filter and set all the needed parameters, it works but im not able to display a "normal" YT page on chrome to do my research, any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71975098) solves your issue?