# My Exo player not working with youtube url?

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, exoplayer

> I used Youtube extractor library https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor
> it is showing

java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=TNAMFEo07PU&eurl=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.googleapis.com%2Fv%2FTNAMFEo07PU

Comment: If you have [opened an issue on the GitHub HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor repository](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/issues) (and I recommend you to do so if you haven't done it before asking on StackOverflow) please share the link to it here.

Comment: In the solution It is said add &html5 =1 
where to add this

Comment: Not solving the problem, just helping others to dig from your question: [a very commented GitHub issue](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/issues/196) and [a StackOverflow related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615278/get-video-info-youtube-endpoint-suddenly-returning-404-not-found/67629882#67629882). It seems that [there isn't anymore just to modify the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711617/7123660). May you precise what data are you expecting to extract from this URL ?